# Django: slow performance navigating generic foreign keys

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, foreign-keys

My Django app has a bunch of different `Widget` model classes. They all inherit from an abstract model `BaseWidget` and despite their many differences, they have a few common fields (such as `price`, `name`, etc). I also have a `Package` model, which is intended to represent an ordered collection of widgets (maybe from different classes), along with some metadata. Here is an example package:

```
[<FooWidget: 4>, <BarWidget: 1>, <BarWidget: 5>, <BangWidget: 1>]
```

An example task would be summing up the `price` of all widgets in a package, or printing a list of widgets in the correct order.

Currently, my implementation is that every `Widget` has a ForeignKey to a `Package`. The `Package` has a `GenericForeignKey` to the first `Widget` called `first_widget`, and each `Widget` has a `GenericForeignKey` called `next_widget`. To iterate through a package's widgets, I follow the next_widget relations like a linked list. This is very slow and I am looking for a better way.

One idea I have is to have a field on the `Package` called `widget_tuples` that is a list of `(WidgetClass, pk)` tuples. If I could figure out an efficient way to serialize/deserialize this Python data structure to my DB (e.g. by pickling), then I could reconstruct the list by doing:

```
widgets = [WidgetClass.objects.get(pk) for WidgetClass,pk in self.widget_tuples]
```

Can anyone comment on this approach or point me in a better direction?

(By the way, the list of widgets in a package does not change dynamically; i.e. widgets are not added or removed.)

Comment: Could you post your models? Sometimes the answer is to simplify matters by changing the base models.

Answer (score 0):

Using different classes - not good solution. One widget - one query or more.
I think you need one Widget class and methods for serialization custom widgets. 
Also you need dynamic Form field creation, for example from json data. In form - override is_valid method and save data into Widget model. 
For json i recommend ujson lib.